# general spectral theory for compact self-adjoint operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

If $T$ is a compact self -adjoint operator on Hilbet space $H$ and $\{\lambda_1\cdots\}$ is the set of eigenvalues of $T$, then $T=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda_i P_i$, where $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection from $H$ to $\ker(T-\lambda_i)$.

There is a general spectral theorem (see Conway's book): if $T$ is a normal operator on $H$,  then there exists a spectral measure $\mu$ on the borel subsets of $\sigma(N)$ such that $T=\int z \mathrm{d}\mu(z)$.

If $T$ is compact and self-adjoint, how to use the general spectral theorem to conclude that $\mu(\lambda_i)=P_i$, where $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalue of $T$.

Comment: "T" became "N"?

Comment: In the first edition of Conway's book, this is exercise 3 in the section on the spectral theorem.  Given that this is an exercise, can you provide some of your thoughts/attempts?  As a hint, first work through exercise 1 of that section.  After that, things become pretty clear.

Comment: @Aweygan, first edtion? I just found the second edition online. The first part of exercise 1 is $\lambda\in \sigma_p (T)\subseteq \sigma(T)$ iff $\mu(\lambda)\neq 0$. If $\lambda \in \sigma_p(T)$, then $\ker (T-\lambda)\neq 0$, but I cannot prove that $\mu(\lambda)\neq 0$.